# How to redirect Guest user to create account page in onepagecheckout in magento1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, guest-checkout

How to redirect Guest user to create account page in onepage-checkout ?

After creating the account, must redirect to onepage-checkout as logged in user.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: check the updated question

Comment: please check updated answer for extension

Comment: Still not redirecting to create account page for guest user in onepagecheckout.

Answer (score 0):

Its about to setting change in `magento` you can achieve by just disable the guest checkout

login to admin panel and after that go to

`system->configuration->sales->checkout->Checkout Options-> Allow Guest Checkout`

set this setting to `no`

**[Edit]**
And forgot to mention

go to

`system->configuration->customer->customer configuration->Login option->  Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in`
Set this field to `no`

**[End Edit]**

Also You can check for below extension

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-redirection.html

It will give you sign up redirection option so you can redirect at any page after sign up. just give relative url for that

and clear the cache and your work is done enjoy your day.

Comment: i have done this step.no use of it.

Comment: it will will not redirecting to login page for guest user

Comment: please check updated answer for extension

Comment: Still not redirecting to create account page for guest user in onepagecheckout.